# remove last character '?' from the URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect urls from website A to website B.
after redirection with htaccess, the urls on the website B are like www.site.com?id_event=999

to resolve this and to remove the query string id_event.. I added '?' at the end of the target url.
Now I can't see (id_event=999) on the website B, but the '?' appear on the url.
But I need to remove the ? from the url

Can I make  another redirection via htaccess on website B to delete the '?' at the end of the URL or is there another solution to delete the query string?

## htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.xpx


#Parcours Actualites

RewriteRule ^actualites/(.*)_([0-9]*)\.html$ /Actualites/Actualite.xpx?id_evenement=$2


# ajouter le lien actualites pour remplacer /actualite
RewriteRule ^actualites$ /Actualites/Actualite.xpx



#1
redirect 301 /actualite/choisir-un-sous-traitant-tolerie-fine-pour-produire-des-pieces-complexes_382.html   https://www.metal-interface.fr/actualite/choisir-un-sous-traitant-tolerie-fine-pour-produire-des-pieces-complexes_382.html?

#2 #
redirect 301 /actualite/presses-plieuses-electriques-les-5-criteres-de-choix_343.html https://www.metal-interface.com/presses-plieuses-electriques-les-5-criteres-de-choix?

RewriteRule  ^actualite/presses-plieuses-electriques\xC2\xA0-les-5-criteres-de-choix_343\.html$  https://www.metal-interface.com/presses-plieuses-electriques-les-5-criteres-de-choix? [L,NC,R=301]

#3
redirect 301 /news/electric-press-brakes-the-5-criteria-of-choice_350.html  https://www.metal-interface.com/en/electric-press-brakes-5-criteria-choice?
#4
redirect 301 /news/elektrische-abkantpressen-5-auswahlkriterien_355.html https://www.metal-interface.com/de/elektrische-abkantpressen-5-auswahlkriterien?

#5
redirect 301 /news/presse-piegatrici-elettriche-i-5-criteri-di-scelta_351.html  https://www.metal-interface.com/it/presse-piegatrici-elettriche-i-5-criteri-di-scelta?

....
```

Comment: sure, I edited the post

Comment: Instead of `redirect` use `RewriteRule` for all rules and test in a new browser or clear browser cache.

Comment: Thank you ! It works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, using Rewrite `RewriteRule` instead of `redirect` resolved the query string problem!

add [L,R=301] to have same seo result of redirect 301.